# Are these statements true or false? (Which congruence class does the Jacobi symbol $(\frac {a}{b})$ depend on?)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Statement 1: For non-zero natural numbers $a$, $b$ which are relatively prime, the Jacobi symbol
$(\frac {a}{b})$

depends only on the congruence class of $a$ modulo $b$.

I believe this is false because I think it depends on whether or not $a$ and $b$ are $1$ or $3$ mod $4$.  Is this reasoning correct?

Statement 2: For non-zero natural numbers $a$, $b$
which are relatively prime, the Jacobi symbol ($\frac {a}{b})$

depends only on the congruence class of
$b$ modulo $4a$.

I think this statement is true by the quadratic reciprocity theorem.  Is this reasoning correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Neither statement is correct.

Counterexample for the first

$(41,26)$ and $(93,26)$

and for the second

$(7,20)$ and $(7,76)$

Comment: Could you please expand on why they're incorrect then?

Comment: To be honest, I did not find these counter-examples by hand, but with the PARI/GP-calculator. Just calculate the jacobi-symbols and verify whether they are equal.

Comment: Ok but a Jacobi symbol (a/b) must be dependent on the congruence class of b modulo a, no?

Comment: Yes, but not only as the counter-examples show.

Comment: I don't see how the counterexamples don't show that to be honest. Could you show me exactly how the counterexample shows otherwise?

Comment: Statement $1$ : (a/b) only depends on a modulo b. The pairs (41,26) and (93,26) have the same value a modulo b, but the jacobi-symbols are different. So, the jacobi-symbol cannot ONLY depend on the value a modulo b. Analogue for the second statement.

Comment: I follow. But why is the second statement false? I follow that you provided a counterexample. However, without a calculator, how would one go about showing that it is false?

Comment: That is another matter. I will think about it ...